# URL Rewrite multiple AND conditional redirect

Tags: c#, url, url-rewriting

I am looking for a URL Rewrite rule to redirect any request made to [www.XYZ.com](http://www.XYZ.com), inte.XYZ.com, prep.XYZ.com, and prod.XYZ.com from the list of IP subnets below to redirect to https://test.XYZ.com.

111.000.111.0/24

111.111.222.0/22

111.222.333.0/24

I have written the rule as below:

```
<rule name="RedirectToXYZTest" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.XYZ\.com$|^inte\.XYZ\.com$|^prep\.xyz\.com$|^prod\.xyz\.com$" />
      <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^111\.000\.111\.\d{1,3}$" />
      <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^111\.111\.222\.\d{1,3}$" />
      <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^111\.222\.333\.\d{1,3}$" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.xyz.com/" />
</rule>
```

The issue with the above is that the condition works even with any one condition because of the matchany logical condition.
I need an AND condition of Http_Host && one of the Ip address to perform the redirect action.

ie if the url is
[www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) ,any of the Ip address range in the given regex like 111.000.111.3 should fullfil the criteria to redirect.

Cant find any precondition for inbound rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first idea comes to my mind is to define three different rules using `MatchAll`:

```
<rules>
   <rule name="RedirectToXYZTest1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.XYZ\.com$|^inte\.XYZ\.com$|^prep\.xyz\.com$|^prod\.xyz\.com$" />
         <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^111\.000\.111\.\d{1,3}$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.xyz.com/" />
   </rule>
   <rule name="RedirectToXYZTest2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.XYZ\.com$|^inte\.XYZ\.com$|^prep\.xyz\.com$|^prod\.xyz\.com$" />
         <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^111\.111\.222\.\d{1,3}$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.xyz.com/" />
   </rule>
   <rule name="RedirectToXYZTest3" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.XYZ\.com$|^inte\.XYZ\.com$|^prep\.xyz\.com$|^prod\.xyz\.com$" />
         <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^111\.222\.333\.\d{1,3}$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.xyz.com/" />
   </rule>
</rules>
```

Comment: This will work but from code readability perspective ,there are a lot of repetitive code that I cannot use the approach but your solution gave me an idea on how i can achieve it. I can consolidate the pattern into one using ORing in Remote_ADDR. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the consolidated regex pattern that i have used.
The default logicalGrouping is MatchAll which will verify for http_Host && Remote Addr
Note:
REMOTE_ADDR will only work locally & so it is good from testing the rule locally.Once deployed, it will not contain the real IP of the visitor.
The rule needs to be for HTTP_True_Client_IP instead of Remote_ADDR for production.

```
<rule name="RedirectToXYZTest" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.XYZ\.com$|^inte\.XYZ\.com$|^prep\.xyz\.com$|^prod\.xyz\.com$" />
      <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^111\.000\.111\.\d{1,3}$|^111\.111\.222\.\d{1,3}$^111\.222\.333\.\d{1,3}$" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.xyz.com/" />
</rule>
```

Regards.